# Has anyone experienced slow delayed job processing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm trying to use delayed_job to have the background job to process the lengthy tasks but in my controller when I added the delay job there is a pretty significant delayed, from less then 50ms to over 1000ms and it's not what I expected. Does anyone experience this problem and know the workaround for this?

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Answer (score 2):

Delayed Job is database based, so if you'r DB is under load that could explain why it takes from 50 to 1000ms.

Take a look at Sidekiq, it uses Redis to handle the queues so your performance wont be tied to the DB.

Comment: I use mongodb and it's on my test server which has practically zero load. I can do other inserts and updates in the same controller and those operations are done in less than 1ms.

Answer (score 0):

There is a config called `sleep_delay` which means when there is no job in queue, delayed_job would go to sleep in [sleep_time] secs, i.e., the first job inserted in the empty queue may be delayed in [sleep_delay] secs and it happens frequently if your queue is always in empty. Try to tune this config and see the situation is improved or not.

Another possible case is there are too many jobs in queue and the worker can not handle them immediately . This happens if your jobs take long time to run and only one single worker is used. Try to use multiple workers in your project if in this case.

Comment: I tried to tweak the sleep_delay config but it didn't help and there is piratically no job in the queue because it's my dev server. The issue I'm experiencing is not the speed for the delayed_job worker to run the jobs in the queue, the slowness is on the time it takes to created (actually I can see that the db insert took less than 1ms, but I think the logic in the lib takes over 1000ms) a delayed job.

Comment: It's weird. A job should be inserted immediately when a delayed method is called. Note that the parameters used in a delayed method are stored in the serialized format(you can check the table and see how they are stored in db), i.e., if the sent object is complex, it may cause some issues. But I never see the similar problem before.

Comment: I'll try experimenting with a new rails project to see if I observe the same issue. More update to come!!

Comment: Was able to try a new rails project and didn't see the delay in rails 3.2 and 4.1.

Comment: Later I found it's the workless gem that slows it down.

https://github.com/lostboy/workless